# How to show that the set is open?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ is a smooth manifold, and let $p,q$ be points of $M$. If we define
$$
E_p:=\{q\in M: \text{p and q can be connected by a piecewise smooth curve}    \},
$$
how to show that $E_p$ is open and $M\setminus E_p$ is open ($M\setminus E_p=\{x\in M:x \notin E_p  \}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q \in E_p$ be arbitrary. We pick a chart $\phi: O \to \mathbb R^d$, where $O \subseteq M$ is open and $q \in O$. Then for any $x \in O$, we can connect $q$ and $x$ by the smooth curve

$$
\gamma: [0, 1] \to M, \gamma(t) := \phi^{-1}((1-t)\phi(q) + t \phi(x)).
$$

Hence, $O \subseteq E_p$. Since $q$ was arbitrary, $E_p$ is open.

Let now $z \in M \setminus E_p$ be arbitrary. One again, we pick a chart $\phi: O \to \mathbb R^d$, where $O \subseteq M$ is open and $z \in O$. Now if there is any point $y$ contained within $E_p \cap O$, then the smooth curve
$$
\gamma: [0, 1] \to M, \gamma(t) := \phi^{-1}((1-t)\phi(q) + t \phi(y)).
$$
would connect $y$ and $q$, and since $y$ is connected to $p$, $q$ is connected to $p$ and hence $q \in E_p$, contradiction. Hence, $E_p \cap O = \emptyset$, and thus $O \subseteq M \setminus E_p$. Since $q$ was arbitrary, $M \setminus E_p$ is open.